# WCF URL Routing

Tags: c#, wcf, url-routing

I have a WCF Service hosted using a Windows Service Application. All configurations are exposed by the app.config file.
This is the way I start the WCF Host:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
    // provide the base address.
    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MonitorService));

    // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
    // listening for messages.
    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

And this is how I configured by Monitor Service in the app.config:

```
<service name="blabla.Services.MonitorService">
  <endpoint address="Monitor" behaviorConfiguration="webBeahvior" binding="webHttpBinding"
            name="monitorEndpoint" contract="blabla.Services.IMonitorService" />
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9400" />
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
</service>
```

Now, if I hit the url http://localhost:9400 I get the default WCF help page. If I hit http://localhost:9400/Monitor I get **endpoint not found** and if I hit http://localhost:9400/Monitor/Health, which is a web method, I get my JSON back.

Is it possible to configure some routing so that the addresses http://localhost:9400 return a specific service method and same concept for the url http://localhost:9400/Monitor?

I mark my WCF methods like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
HealthResponseMessage Health();
```

Comment: Did you try defining a URITemplate?
E.g. [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Monitor...

Comment: So if I had /something I completely override the URI?

Comment: Yap, I think it's best if you give it a shot and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: No really what I need, with UriTemplate you override the segment of the method name but there is not trick to make an URL rewrite that call a specific method when the user hit the root url http://localhost:9400

Comment: You can define ISAPI filter using .NET's URLRewrite, try reading about it in MSDN, there is pretty good documentation